# Set ForeignKey value from url parameter in Django's CreateView

Tags: django, dry, django-class-based-views

```
class Event(models.Model):
  ...

class Question(models.Model):
  event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

And I have url pattern like `/events/(?P<event_id>\d+)/question/add/$` bound to `QuestionCreateView`

```
QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.event = [???]
        return super(QuestionCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

What I'd like to get:

- throw a 404 error if user requests invalid `event_id` like `/events/9999999/objects/add/`
- get an `Event` instance from url's `event_id` and populate my new `Question` instance before saving
- do it in a DRY way, since I have some other models with relations like this

Is it possible with class-based views? It looks like some crazy mix of `DetailView` for `Event` and `CreateView` for `Question`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url keyword arguments are available in the view as [`self.kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.event = get_object_or_404(Event,
                                                pk=self.kwargs['event_id'])
        return super(QuestionCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```